# jodatime javadoc documents does not show up in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jodatime

I am trying to use joda-time in Android Studio. I have added `joda-time-2.3.jar` and `joda-time-2.3-javadoc.jar` to the `libs` folder of my app. The problem is when I hit `ctrl+q`to show the quick documentation about the method that I want to use, it does not show anything.

I wonder how can I make the Android Studio to load the documentation for the joda-time? any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option #1**

You can expand the `joda-time-2.3.jar` node in the Project View (under libs), open any of the classes inside, and then select "Attach Sources".

In the file picker, just select the `joda-time-2.3-sources.jar` file. And you're done.

**Option #2**

You could also include the JodaTime dependency via gradle/maven instead of including the jar file. For that, just remove the `compile files('libs/joda-time-2.3.jar')` line in `build.gradle` (as well as the jar file itself) and add in its place:

```
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
```

That will automatically download the library, as well as its source jar.

Comment: @Sean87 You're welcome. For more information on this, you can check http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Dependencies-Android-Libraries-and-Multi-project-setup